# Is it possible to pull property detail using IDXBroker API

Tags: php, wordpress, idx, idxbroker

I'm new to IDX implementation , I need to pull and display property details from IDX Listing using IDXBroker API , Is it possible to retrieve property details from IDXBroker API using the API key .

Answer (score 0):

You currently can get property data, but only property data belonging to the agent or agents on the IDX Broker account.

At this time you can not query all data in an MLS.